# Simulated bode plot in Simplis is different from the result of Mathcad

Tags: simulation, buck

I built an open-loop-controlled buck converter in Simplis.
The parameters are listed below:

\$V_g=12V,V_{out}=5V\$

\$D=0.52\$

\$C=100\mu F,ESR=5m\Omega; L=30\mu H,ESR=5m\Omega\$

I use Simplis to simulate the bode plot of \$G_{v_d}\$. And I use the Mathcad to simulate the same circuit. But the result was different. During the low frequency, the peak gain margin in Simplis is less than 0db, while in the Mathcad, the gain was about 20DB.

Here are the results I got.

the circuit in Simplis

[image: the circuit in Simplis]
the Gain bode plot in Simplis

[image: the Gain bode plot in Simplis]

the code in Mathcad

[image: the code in Mathcad]

the curve in Mathcad

[image: the curve in Mathcad]

I don't know what kind of mistake leads to this result. If someone knows the reason, would you please tell me? I am a freshman in Power electric and I appreciate your guidance .

Comment: What about Ron for the FET & diode? Not 0?

Comment: Also V5 must be >2* Vgs(th) max =>8V pref 2.5 x unless you were given to use this in app.

Comment: ESR for cap = 5mOhm ? or 25mOhm which sounds more reasonable.  If Ron =0 Q= 25 dB

Comment: Very underdamped even with 5m switch https://tinyurl.com/y7puk4yt

Comment: Thanks so much, I haven't considered these things in detail. I need to research more about them definitely. There are still lots of unknown things to me.

Comment: You can use http://www.Falstad.com/afilter to model any filter and raise impedances as required on active filters or try different complex passive filters then imagine that a DCDC switches the filter with different R switches for an open loop understanding  of damping ratios by changing or removing the load. Then search my answers for RLC nomograph for easy lookup of “ballpark” LC impedance ratios at any f for series or parallel to estimate Q.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The control-to-outout transfer function of the CCM buck operated in voltage-mode control is the following:

[image]

Several comments regarding your results:

- in Mathcad, you have missed the pulse-width modulator (PWM) gain which is \$G_{PWM}=\frac{1}{V_p}\$ with \$V_p\$ the peak of the modulation ramp. This is your source \$V_3\$ in the SIMPLIS file. It must obviously appear in the control-to-output transfer function that will use for analytical results.
- the quality factor includes many contributors as you can see. In the formulas, these are values of passive elements such as ohmic losses of the capacitor and inductor. In reality, other losses affect \$Q\$ such as the MOSFET \$r_{DS(on)}\$, the diode recovery losses and even magnetic losses. This is the reason why you may see differences between your Mathcad analysis and the SIMPLIS one or a bench prototype. To make sure you have very close results between simulations and Mathcad, chose perfect switches in SIMPLIS (and not a MOSFET), 0-\$V_f\$ diodes etc. Finally, you may be interested to import SIMPLIS simulation results directly in Mathcad to superimpose magnitude and phase curves. See [here](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/Divers/SIMPLIS%20data%20import%20Mathcad.pdf) for a tutorial.

Finally, you can have a look at the 60+ simulation templates I posted [here](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/Book/Christophe%20Basso%20SIMPLIS%20Collection.pdf) for my next book on small-signal modeling of switching converters (TOC is [here](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/Book/TOC%20smallsignal.pdf)). Most of the examples work on Elements, the demo version and you can explore many structures.

Comment: Thanks so much, I realized the problem might occur because of the transfer function, but I didn't know how to derive it. Your answer is instructive. The resource you provided is also helpful, I will research it further.

Comment: This is good, I'm glad if I can help. Please acknowledge the answer if this what you were looking for, thank you. If you are interested in small-signal modeling, you can have a look at my [APEC 2013](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202013.pdf) and [APEC 2014](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202014.pdf) seminars or more specifically on the buck with [APEC 2019](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202019.pdf).

Comment: excellent answer. Reminds me of my time with Keith Billings in the 80's  qualifying his designs

Comment: Merci Monsieur Stewart, I have been in touch several times with Keith long time ago : )

Comment: Mei oui. He wrote the 1st book.  Brown was another expert.

Comment: Cuk would pretend more than he knew about sinusoidal, precision forward converters designs that required no shielding. with quad outputs and extremely low cost  for  HV laser printers ha. what a fox...

Comment: For the "open-loop lossless" Buck, please explain what happens to Q because with no load Q= ∞

Comment: I am suggesting something is wrong with equation for Q as lossless switch and LC , drops out L in the result.

Comment: yet in order to trade off 1% ripple with 1% overshoot,  T max on switch time must have a relationship with ζ = 1/2Q  and L/R and RC

Comment: I checked the \$Q\$ definition and it is correct. If parasitics drop to zero, you have \$Q=R_L\sqrt{\frac{C_2}{L_1}}\$ which is ok.

Comment: sorry, I have another question. In the equation \$H_0=\frac{V_in}{V_P}*\frac{R_{load}}{R_{load+R_L}}\$,why should I have the \$\frac{R_{load}}{R_{load+R_L}}\$,I didn't unserstand what does it mean.

Comment: This is because the ohmic losses reduce the output voltage. In dc analysis, the \$r_L\$ component which is present in the mesh during the on- and off-times forms a resistive divider with the load resistance hence its presence in the small-signal gain. You'll have more details in this [article](http://www.how2power.com/newsletters/1805/articles/H2PToday1805_design_ONSemi.pdf?NOREDIR=1) that I published some time ago.

Answer (score 1):

Additional info and important take-aways on ideal lossless **open-loop** Buck converters: ( THINGS can go horribly wrong with the wrong load)

The equation for Q for \$r_C=r_L=r_{SW}=0,~~~\$, \$Q=C\omega_o,~~~~ Q=C\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{LC}} =R_L\sqrt {\dfrac{C}{L}}~~~~~~~~, \$   \$\omega_o=\dfrac{1}{2\pi f_o}\$

This only works when the SMPS is loaded. Otherwise with no load Q rises to infinity with RL.

So for the critical damping load = \$Q=1/2\zeta_{(zeta_=0.707)}~~~= C\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{LC}} =R_L\sqrt {\dfrac{C}{L}}\$

- thus the critical value is \$R_L=\sqrt{\dfrac{L}{8C}}\$

  - If R is 10 times higher it will look like below.
    [image]

Then for Vpp ripple voltage to be <=1% f must exceed the value for dV/dt=Ic/C where \$dt~ 1/2f\$  so \$f_{min}=\dfrac{Ic}{2C*dV}\$   for Vpp=dV

I'll let you figure out f(min) for Load=1.5A, L=100uH, C=100uF, R=3.3 and dV=dI*R 0.1% of Vout=5V = 5mV,  assuming ideal rC=rL=rSW=0. but Ic is not load current.

*(this is why IC's use more complex startup Imax, good stability and ripple compensation)*

Here again ideal Open-Loop but with a critical damping load.

[image]

[Interactive Browser Simulation by Falstad](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgbALCDMB0AMAOCFoE5EHYBMjoFMBaREARgjFkXlIFZpbSxNFFcwRUz5PsRaipeACgA5uGxRyUMJLJgei4QHlwrEGg44emkEoA2naH10RqGjooTwbaO-YeO0ZWrFKZ4YNKTSYwpRDo0MU5zUlxQnmk9PWEAY0iLRPCSKxtbJ0y7fmtENFxGMGNA2ih4a1JhJh5oZCSGEw5SMkE%20IXSOjuEAJRhaPnNcEnNFTii%20UfLaEOh4KXCYObIUGJEAdz62hdn5ieEABxBMfvkePxJqsk5Yw%201wKExoDkgr5vXE011dEQBnCShdLIpBFRgAzACG%20h%20%20GEACd-mQIkDlmU9LBoNBhAAPEDYFiLfi0WgwaDXcggACSABN8JCADo-AAWkNBhAARrCAJZU0T4Bl08EM2G0uIAF3BADs4vhYAyABT6AD2Px%20%20nwKoAlAcjthxiRHk0Is09hswOoUmoSN9tXcfHxjm18ldSe9bU6zRcnSJek8LtszSiYgMFDZ%20GG4OQgtgwPRaHlMGgXbAIExEMJTUgksjdJVoB5OF8OP0rU0ru9s891Nb4SmOKZjEk0h1KhtagCOLWki3%20BFAZnrab1C87i9y%20aFJayF705OLR7TrENg6F-PLmOSC95wPZxFbSCZ6hGkY%20KOD%20ZTOZT4dD-dEi9mmVtZ2LTeLQ-F8fESQb9vnxFO9aEDwKSdpkH4-ArNgcg8GAAD6QiSLBmCwWYHiwbQsHlKQmHwbBxjwLBAAKnISsIirXIwEynDYfCuLY2DQBAcbhDYGJlNYNBBtcpIADLKAAggAImRuI8JRMTVDYbwcc0dBuAmEAYI88DeDQnE8HwuowCAfFCSJcjiVEIbqTJLjokxaAUI8RIsH4qKaVApIUhK%20wAK6igyADCrmwsKEqivpUCGYipRNKQsBZE4qSmRpuKOSAADKaycqKcSMvgVIMgAboq%20jiryIlBQsRnpNJpVkLA9DRogpSBP4wF0Fx8WefxhHCLUZAumi0nEt06qcj84pSjCHU%20Np7ShrqHQgAAYsKACOrn4FKACe7WemGQGwAGEDYNtJCCe5K1eStcRqutuKrBxUloh0kWZJSEpUq5YqStKwhAA)

Comment: thanks so much, so changing the load could result in the damping factor Q of the transfer function. I will derive it by myself later. The simulation is really intuitive.